# Data not saved permanently in Centos 6 in Oracle VM Virtual box on Reboot

Tags: virtualbox, centos6

I downloaded CentOS-6.5-x86_64-LiveDVD.iso file and installed in Oracle VM Virtual Box but whenever I reboot Centos 6 all my data is getting deleted i.e data is not stored permanently in centos os.

Can you please help me out so that I can persist my changes permanently in Cent OS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you re-booting from cent-os or restarting the VM from virtual Box directly ? the later does not allow changes to be committed to disk..